# Apply function to specific elements in list

Tags: list-manipulation, map

Say I have a list like `myData={{1,m1,v1},{2,m2,v2},{3,m3,v3},{4,m4,v4}}`. It could be a dataset, where the first and second variables in each tuple is as desired, but I want to transform the third argument only. This dataset can be rather long, with possibly hundreds of entries.

In my case, I would much rather have the following set: `myDataLog={{1,m1,Log10[v1]},{2,m2,Log10[v2]},{3,m3,Log10[v3]},{4,m4,Log10[v4]}}`.

Hence my question: how do I apply a function (here: `Log10`) to the third (or, in general, a specific) argument of the list `myData` only? I tried `Log10[myData]` but that takes the log of all entries, not just the third one.

Comment: Take a look at `MapAt`

Comment: Thanks! But `MapAt[Log10, myData, 3]` just takes the log of the third argument {3,m3,v3}, and not of each third element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you didn't mean to have `Table` as the head of your list, but just a simple list:

```
myData = {{1, m1, v1}, {2, m2, v2}, {3, m3, v3}, {4, m4, v4}};
```

Then the following two options would work:

```
MapAt[Log, myData, {All, 3}]
{#1, #2, Log[#3]}& @@@ myData

(* {1, m1, Log[v1]}, {2, m2, Log[v2]}, {3, m3, Log[v3]}, {4, m4, Log[v4]} *)
```

Comment: You are right, sorry, I got that confused. It is indeed a list, and both of your methods work very well. Thank you, I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `SubsetMap` for this purpose:

```
myData = {{1, m1, v1}, {2, m2, v2}, {3, m3, v3}, {4, m4, v4}};
SubsetMap[Log10, myData, {All, 3}]
```

---

```
> {{1, m1, Log[v1]/Log[10]}, {2, m2, Log[v2]/Log[10]}, {3, m3, Log[v3]/ 
> Log[10]}, {4, m4, Log[v4]/Log[10]}}
```