# Change specific elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, manipulate, string-manipulation, map

I have currently looking to change specific elements of a list.
I saw that you can apply a fonction to an element if you know it's position as shown in this question : [Apply function to specific elements in list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/273291/apply-function-to-specific-elements-in-list)

But im looking how to change elements due to their value.
Ex:  I have the list "a":

`a = {{1,0,0},{1,3,2},{1,2,2}}` I would like to change all the 2 into 0 ( note that in this case, I can easily find the position of the 2 but im looking for a general way) ;

Something like `MapAt[#-2&,a,{All,#==2&}]`

How can I achived something like this ?
Thank you in advanced

Comment: Try with: `a /. n_ /; n == 2 :> 0`

Comment: It's work perfectly ty

Comment: Or just `a /. 2 -> 0`